# read many files in to R and merge those with the same name, different suffix

Tags: r

So I need to find a way to read in lot's of files to R, many with the same name, and merge the ones with the same name but a different suffix e.g. all files are a version of "results.[outcome].[person].cohort.[ethnicity].initial-%d.txt.gz", whereby each time the words in square brackets can change, and each file has a different suffix - 1-22.

I want to merge the files with the same name, but a different suffix, so each '[same-name][suffix].txt.gz' becomes one results file.

I can do one by one:

```
# Create a list to store data frames from individual files
file_data_list <- list()

# Loop through numbers from 1 to 22
for (i in 1:22) {
  # Construct the filename for the current number
  filename <- sprintf("results.[outcome].[person].cohort.[ethnicity].initial-%d.txt.gz", i)
  
  # Check if the file exists, and if so, read it into a data frame
  if (file.exists(filename)) {
    file_data <- fread(filename, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
    file_data_list[[i]] <- file_data
  }
}

# Merge all data frames into one
merged_data <- do.call(rbind, file_data_list)

# Write the merged data to a file

write.table(merged_data, "results.[outcome].[person].cohort.[ethnicity].initial.all.txt", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

However can't figure out how to do it for all different file names?

I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

file_names <- list.files(pattern = "results.*cohort.*\\.txt\\.gz", ignore.case = TRUE)
file_names <- file_names[!grepl("index", file_names, ignore.case = TRUE)]

# Function to extract the base name up to the '-' sign
get_base_name <- function(file_name) {
  parts <- strsplit(file_name, "-")[[1]]
  if (length(parts) > 1) {
    return(parts[1])
  } else {
    return(file_name)
  }
}

merged_data <- file_names %>%
  map(read_file) %>%
  map(~ fread(.x, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")) %>%
  map(~ {
    base_name <- get_base_name(.x)
    list(base_name = base_name, data = .)
  }) %>%
  reduce(function(x, y) {
    if (identical(colnames(x$data), colnames(y$data))) {
      x$data <- rbind(x$data, y$data)
    }
    return(x)
  })

# Optionally, if you want to reset row names (rownames)
rownames(merged_data$data) <- NULL
```

But get the error

```
Error in strsplit(file_name, "-") : non-character argument
```

And when I try changing the types to character this doesn't help.

I have tried:

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

# Read the list of file names from list.txt
file_names <- readLines("list.txt")

# Function to read and process files with the same base name
read_and_process_files <- function(base_name) {
  matching_files <- grep(base_name, file_names, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
  
  data_list <- list()
  
  for (file_name in matching_files) {
    if (file.exists(file_name)) {
      file_data <- fread(file_name, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
      data_list[[length(data_list) + 1]] <- file_data
    }
  }
  
  if (length(data_list) > 0) {
    combined_data <- rbindlist(data_list)
    return(combined_data)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

# Generate the base names (e.g., "file_name-1.txt.gz" becomes "file_name")
base_names <- sub("-\\d+\\.txt\\.gz", "", file_names)

# Filter out base names that end with 'index'
base_names <- base_names[!grepl("index$", base_names, ignore.case = TRUE)]

# Get unique base names
unique_base_names <- unique(base_names)

# Use purrr's map_df to read and combine all files with the same base name
combined_data_list <- map_df(unique_base_names, read_and_process_files)

# Optionally, if you want to reset row names (rownames)
rownames(combined_data_list) <- NULL
```

Which doesn't work because it's trying to merge files which do not have the same name - I know this because I get the error

```
Error in rbindlist(data_list) :
  Item 2 has 1 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 23 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.
```

And the files with the same names are all the same N of columns

Any ideas?